# A question about a tag badge that I have earned today

Tags: support, badges

Today when I logged in, I was notified that I have earned the "smriti" tag badge, which is a bronze badge.

You can verify that from the link: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/badges/173/smriti

The same page also says the following about when the badge is awarded. "Earn at least 100 total score for at least 20 non-community wiki answers in the smriti tag."

But my score for this particular tag is 194. This can be verified from the link: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/tags/smriti/topusers

Question -- Then why did I earn the badge today when I have reached the required score of 100 much earlier? Is there something that I am missing here to note?

Comment: May be due to lockdown :P

Comment: I have earned few other badges during lockdown too but they were not tag badges. You can see from [this link](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/4732/rickross?tab=activity&sort=badges) @hanugm

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One can only earn tag badges on those tags that are attached to at least 100 questions (see [What are the badges I can earn on each site, and what are the exact criteria for earning each badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/what-are-the-badges-i-can-earn-on-each-site-and-what-are-the-exact-criteria-for#68395)).

> What are tag badges?
>
> ---
>
> Users may earn badges on any site for positive contributions to
> established tags used on that site. Each tag badge has the same name
> as the tag for which it was awarded.
>
> When a user meets the requirements for a tag badge that has never been
> awarded, the system creates and awards it automatically. These badges
> are displayed with a white background, unlike other badges that are
> displayed with a black background.
>
> **Tag badges are only issued for tags that are being used on at least 100 questions.** Additionally, tag badges are not issued for tags that
> have the same name as a non-tag badge.

The hundredth question tagged [smriti](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/smriti) was asked only [yesterday](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/42364/how-to-increase-memory), at which point you earned the badge due to having at least 20 non-community wiki answers with total score at least 100 in this tag.

Comment: Ok cool observation. Thanks!

Comment: I reproduced the relevant texts from that MSE answer here.